# Copies of same file in numerous folders... How to find deepest copy?

Tags: linux, bash, find

So I have many music projects organized in their own folders. Each project has a file, `album.inf`. Some projects have their own folder, some projects are within other projects that are within other projects and so on, each having their own `album.inf`. I would like to parse through some information within each `album.inf` file but I need to begin with the ones at the deepest levels. How can I list each `album.inf` file, starting with the "deepest" version? Is this possible without writing a lengthy script or function? What might be the best way to go about performing this operation?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Check out this post on how to ask a question that is more likely to be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `find . -depth -name album.inf -print`?

Comment: After some testing this seems like it should work. I could probably clarify that it is NOT important that i start with the deepest iteration of `album.inf`, but each iteration whose directory has no subdirectory in which there exists another occurrence of `album.inf` . Does that make sense? In that case, I think this is exactly the correct solution. Thank you!

Comment: @twalberg I don't think this guarantees that the directory with the deepest nesting is traversed first.

Comment: Ah, with the addition from the comment, it works. Not how I understand the question, though.

Comment: Haha yeah beat ya by 1 second with my clarification. Sorry about that! But you are correct, I found in my testing that this solution does NOT traverse the deepest directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `find` and `sort` you could get a nice list of files to iterate through:

```
find .  -name "album.inf" -printf '%d %p\n' | sort -rn
```

With `printf` `%d` is the token for "depth" and `%p` is the token for file name and that's just piped to sort to give you the list sorted numerically descending

Comment: If you use GNU `find` and `sort`, you can make it safe for all filenames including those containing newlines with `printf '%d %p\0' | sort -rnz`.